# AngularJS ng-required allowing only whitespace

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have an `input[type=text]` on my form with an `ng-required="true"`.
I have a button click event that updates the model that the input is bound to.

If the updated value is blank, the form becomes invalid.
But If the updated value is entirely whitespace, the form is valid.

If you delete the whitespace and readd it, the form becomes invalid again.

This jsfiddle demonstrates: http://jsfiddle.net/dayeh/

Is there a workaround to this issue? For now I will just trim all my back-end data.

Comment: In your fiddle, if I add just spaces the form is invalid. Are you referring to after it is clicked? Also, did you mean to have an empty space in `$scope.myData = ' ';` ?

Comment: Having whitespace in the variable is the whole point. I am demonstating odd behavior. If you manually type in whitespace, ng-required treats it as an error. But if you directly set it to whitepsace, it does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem occurs because of the way `ng-model` works.

By default `ng-model` trims input values. If you look at this [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5WT8/) with quotes around the value you can see that user inputed spaces show up as an empty string.

However if you force the model to be an empty space the trimming is not applied and therefor the model is technically valid.

You can remove the default trimming of `ng-model` with `ng-trim="false"`. Then you'd get the more expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

After clicking on you button, the value gets resets. However, the value is being reset to . An empty whitespace. If I set it to `$scope.myData = '';`, then valid is false (as expected). If I enter whitespace in manually, then valid remains to false.

So I assume <del>`$scope.myData = ' ';`</del> is the problem that you're having. Switch it to `scope.myData = '';`

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/7Bnp4/)

Comment: The fiddle is just demonstrating the issue I found. I intentionally was setting it to a single space. Either way, I think ng-required should be treating it as an error.